# How to create simple remove .php extension with .htaccess page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am newbie of php

How to create simple remove .php extension with .htaccess page?

My aims is type this url http://site/Test
it can visit hello.php content, anyone know how to do that?? thx

I have one folder that call "Test", there are two file on "Test" Folder

```
Test/
  -hello.php
  -.htaccess
```

hello.php

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

finally, it is not successful
it display the following error message

```
**Internal Server Error**
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

anyidea to solve this??? Thank you very much

Comment: Tell us: how should the rewriting engine guess that you are trying to access the file `hello php`? Rewriting cannot somehow magically onvent information.

Comment: You want to take a look at the `DirectoryIndex` directive. Best is to start by looking into the documentation of the tool you use: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: And for general rewriting ideas you will find literally _thousands_ of examples here on SO. And also, obviously, an excellent documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My aims is type this url `http://site/Test` it can visit `hello.php` content, anyone know how to do that?

This isn't simply "file extension removal". If it was then `/Test` would serve the content from `/Test.php`. In your example, you are wanting to serve the contents of an entirely different file.

## Rewriting the request with mod_rewrite

Since you are requesting a *directory* (`/Test/`) and wanting to serve a file from within that directory and the `.htaccess` file itself is actually located in that directory, you would need to write your `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ hello.php [L]
```

In `.htaccess` (*directory* context), the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path relative to the location of the `.htaccess` file. So, in this case the URL-path we are matching against is simply an *empty* string, ie. `^$`, since we are wanting to match `/Test/<nothing>`.

Likewise, when the *susbtitution* string (ie. `hello.php`) is *relative* (as it is here), it is relative to the location of the `.htaccess` file. So, in this case it effectively rewrites the request to `/Test/hello.php` (it's actually the absolute filesystem path, eg. `/var/www/user/public_html/Test/hello.php` - after the directory-prefix is added back).

#### Additional issues with this example

Since you are rewriting a request that would otherwise map to a physical directory there are a couple of potential issues you need to be aware of...

You should request the directory *with* a trailing slash, ie. `/Test/`, not `/Test` (as you stated in your initial example), otherwise mod_dir will issue a 301 redirect to append the slash *before* your rewrite is successful.

(There are ways to avoid the trailing slash, but this does increase the complexity and requires further manual rewrites.)

An additional complication occurs if there is a `DirectoryIndex` document in this subdirectory. eg. `/Test/index.php`. In this case mod_dir issues an internal subrequest to the `DirectoryIndex` document (eg. `index.php`) and this takes priority over your internal rewrite. (Your rewrite does still occur, but mod_dir "wins".) If this is the case then you can rewrite the `DirectoryIndex` document instead of an empty URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ hello.php [L]
```

This is perhaps counter-intuitive, as we are now rewriting the internal subrequest that mod_dir has issued in a later pass through the file.

You could handle both scenarios and make `index.php` *optional*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ hello.php [L]
```

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
> ```

Your example would result in an internal rewrite loop (500 Internal Server Error response) since the *pattern* `^(.*)$` also matches the rewritten URL and it gets stuck in an endless loop. (The rewriting process doesn't just consist of a single pass through the file. The process repeats until the URL passes through unchanged.)

(Incidentally, this IS an extensionless URL type of rewrite, but it doesn't help you achieve what you stated in your example.)

There are various ways to prevent this "endless loop":

- Use a more specific regex, that won't also match the rewritten URL. eg. a regex that excludes a dot such as `^([^.]+)$`.
- Use a `RewriteCond` (condition) directive that prevents the rule being triggered on the rewritten URL. eg. Exclude `.php` files or check that the request does not map to a file, etc.
- Use the `END` flag on the `RewriteRule` to stop *all* further processing by the rewrite engine.

## Alternative - change the `DirectoryIndex`

Instead of using mod_rewrite, as explained above, to internally rewrite the request, we could instead change the `DirectoryIndex` document.

This only works in this particular case where you are requesting a directory and wanting to serve a file from that directory (although strictly speaking the file could be anywhere).

The `DirectoryIndex` is the document that mod_dir will look for when requesting a directory (eg. `/test/`). By default, it looks for `index.html` (and often `index.php`) and possibly others. If a `DirectoryIndex` document is not found, you get a 403 Forbidden when requesting that directory (assuming auto-directory indexes are disabled).

For example, you could set the following:

```
DocumentIndex hello.php
```

And now when you request `/Test/`, mod_dir will serve `hello.php` in that directory.

However, this method (by itself) is limiting and potentially confusing for readers of your code (if changing the `DirectoryIndex` on a directory by directory basis). It is generally expected that the `DirectoryIndex` document(s) is consistent throughout your site.

Comment: `hello.php` is actually inside `Test/` folder

Comment: @anubhava Ah yes, thanks - somehow overlooked that! I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: Indeed DirectoryIndex is best solution ++